# Onblur function keeps running

Tags: javascript, events, onblur

I have an onblur event that will cause an error window to popup if incorrect data is input. The problem is, when I try to close the webpage, or click any other window, the onblur event will activate and the popup will come up again... Anyone have an idea how to fix this?

Here is a simplified version of the code

```
<input id="M3_pos_tab" type="text" maxlength="5" name="Blank" size="5" onblur="CheckFS();"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
function CheckFS()
{
    var FS_pos = parseFloat(FS_tab.value);
    if ((FS_pos == 0) || (FS_pos == parseFloat(L_tab.value)) || (isNaN(FS_pos))) {
    } else {
        window.alert("Error"); 
        FS_tab.select(); 
        FS_tab.focus();  
        return;     
    }
}
```

Comment: What is FS_tab and what does it do?

Comment: @donnywals: My guess is that it's the input element that is calling the function, but I have no idea where that assignment takes place.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that when the error box appears, it takes the focus and therefore it triggers onblur at the element. I found this out at https://javascript.info/focus-blur, which says

> A focus loss can occur for many reasons. One of them is when the visitor clicks somewhere else. But also JavaScript itself may cause it, for instance:
>
> - An alert moves focus to itself, so it causes the focus loss at the element (blur event), and when the alert is dismissed, the focus comes back (focus event).

I therefore suggest removing the line

```
window.alert("Error");
```

and to see if the problems persists.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a form you can utilize onsubmit.

```
<form action="onsubmit.htm" onsubmit="return CheckInput();">
<!-- input -->
<input type="submit" value="send">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function CheckInput () {
// things you want to check
</script>
```

If CheckInput() returns *true* the form will be submitted, if it returns *false* the form will not be sumbitted.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how foolproof this is, but you could check the active element on blur. At least in Chrome, the `onblur` event will still fire when you click on a different window or tab, but the active element will still be the input, and not something else on the page. Kinda hacky solution, but it might work for you:

[Sample fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ELgWQ/)

```
function CheckFS() {
    if (document.activeElement == FS_tab) {
        // if the input is still the active element,
        // then we haven't focused anything else on the page,
        // so we must have focused something else off of the page
        return;
    }

    var FS_pos = parseFloat(FS_tab.value);
    if ((FS_pos == 0) || (FS_pos == parseFloat(L_tab.value)) || (isNaN(FS_pos))) {
    } else {
        window.alert("Error"); 
        FS_tab.select(); 
        FS_tab.focus();  
        return;     
    }
}
```